I need to draw as attached image

my code is:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (solid) at (0,0) [draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] {H$_2$O(s)};
\node (gas) at (0,3) [draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] {H$_2$O(g)};
    

\draw[->, thick] (solid) -- (gas) node[midway, right] {$\Delta H = + 6 \,\text{kJ/mol}$};

    

\node at (0,-1) {$\Delta H > 0$};
\node at (0,-1.5) {$\Delta H = +$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



What is your problem/question? (Please EDIT your question and add it there)

I assume that your problem is to color boxes borders, change borders thickness and draw double line around it. Something like this:

For this image I add to your preamble siunitx (which is missed in your MWE), mhchem and makecell packages, and also load tikz libraries arrows.meta, fit and positioning. Thinner line around boxes is drawn by using fit libraries:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % <-- added
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm,
arr/.style = {-Stealth, thick},
  N/.style = {draw=cyan, very thick, fill=cyan!30, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm},
FIT/.style = {draw=cyan, inner sep=1pt, fit=#1}
                    ]

\node (n1) [N,
            label=below:{\makecell{$\Delta H>0$\\
                                   $\Delta H=0$}}] {\ce{H2O}(s)};
\node (f1) [FIT=(n1)] {};

\node (n2) [N, above=of n1]  {\ce{H2O}(g)};
\node (f2) [FIT=(n2),
            label=below right: {physical change} ] {};
    
\draw[arr] (f1) -- node[right] {$\Delta H_r^\circ = + \qty{6}{\kilo\joule\per\mol}$}  (f2);
\draw[arr] ([xshift=-3mm] f1.south west) -- node[above, sloped] {Energy}  ([xshift=-3mm] f2.north west);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

To my opinion the arrow below equation for added energy is superfluous.
